# How to define variables that will be used in every iteration of a function within a class in python?

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have a class that defines a function `define_stop_words` that returns a list of string tokens. I then went to apply another function called `remove_stopwords`, which takes raw utf8 text as input, to a pandas dataframe `df` which contains text. The code looks something like this

```
class ProcessText:

    def __init__(self, flag):
        self.flag = flag # not important for this question

    def define_stop_words(self):
        names = ['john','sally','billy','sarah']
        stops = ['if','the','in','then','an','a']
        return stops+names

    def remove_stopwords(self, text):
        return [word for word in text if word not in self.define_stop_words()]


 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
 parse = ProcessText(flag=True)
 df['text'] = df['text'].apply(parse.remove_stopwords())
```

My question is, will the `remove_stopwords` function call on and define the variable returned by `define_stop_words` every time - for every word in `text` for every row in `df` (for every iteration basically)?

If this is the case, I don't want it to run like this, as it would be very slow and inefficient. I want to define the variable returned by `define_stop_words` **once**, almost like a "global variable" within the `ProcessText` class, and then use that variable in `remove_stopwords` multiple times (for every word and row in `df`).

Is there a way to do this - should this be done? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Set it on `self` or better yet, the class.

Comment: Totally unrelated but `ProcessText` is a verb, so it's not a proper name for a class - you usually use nouns for classes, objects and variables ("things") and verbs for functions / methods ("actions").`TextProcessor` might be a better candidate. Same thing for the `parse` variable (what about `processor` instead ?)

Comment: also slightly unrelated, I would make `remove_stopwords` a generator, and let the caller take care of making it a `list` or whatever container they want

Comment: Show a few rows from a sample dataframe. I am pretty sure your use of `apply` is completely off base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign those names to class variables as

```
class ProcessText:
   names = ['john','sally','billy','sarah']
   stops = ['if','the','in','then','an','a']

   def __init__(self, flag):
       self.flag = flag # not important for this question

   def remove_stopwords(self, text):
       return [word for word in text if word not in self.names + self.stops]


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
parse = ProcessText(flag=True)
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(parse.remove_stopwords())
```

Those class variables is inherited by all the instances. Assignment in __init__() method will result in multiple assignments each time new instance is created.

Answer (score 2):

You could cache the listed words, setting them in the init so that the operation only gets called once. Then instead of using a define_stop_words() function, you would have this as a property.

```
class ProcessText:

    def __init__(self, flag):
        self.flag = flag # not important for this question
        self._names = ['john','sally','billy','sarah']
        self._stops = ['if','the','in','then','an','a']

    @property
    def define_stop_words(self):
        return self._stops + self._names

    def remove_stopwords(self, text):
        return [word for word in text if word not in self.define_stop_words]
```

Note that in python, there is no real concept of a private variable (*which is what I think you want to use here - you don't want the user to be able to overwrite these lists once created?*). This means that an unscrupulous user of your code could still update the _names and _stops attributes within the ProcessText object after the initialiser, meaning that you get unexpected results.

Another thing to consider is to use a set instead of a list (*especially if performance is an issue*) as the hashing will be faster.

Of course it would be faster again to combine the lists and cache the combined set instead of performing the 'add' on each call to the property too (*so that the property call simply returns a cached set*) if you were nitpicking further!

e.g

```
class ProcessText:

    def __init__(self, flag):
        self.flag = flag # not important for this question
        _names = {'john','sally','billy','sarah'}
        _stops = {'if','the','in','then','an','a'}
        self._stops_and_names = _names.union(_stops)

    @property
    def define_stop_words(self):
        return self._stops_and_names

    def remove_stopwords(self, text):
        return [word for word in text if word not in self.define_stop_words]
```

Comment: Why are you using so much indirection to define a constant? Good advice about using a set though.

Answer (score 2):

The `define_stop_words` method will be called only once every time you call the `remove_stopwords` method.

One way to call it only exactly once per instance, but not when initializing the instance (because you might have many of those methods, all of which are expensive, and you don't always need all of them), is to use something like this:

```
class ProcessText:

    def __init__(self, flag):
        self.flag = flag # not important for this question
        self._stop_words = None

    @property
    def stop_words(self):
        if self._stop_words is None:
            self._stop_words = set(['john','sally','billy','sarah'])
            self._stop_words |= set(['if','the','in','then','an','a'])
        return self._stop_words

    def remove_stopwords(self, text):
        return [word for word in text if word not in self.define_stop_words]
```

Comment: Why not just define it as a class attribute? Why use a method for a constant to begin with?

Comment: @MadPhysicist You are right, in case it really is assimple as the OP claims. If it is actually some expensive function, then doing it like this might be better.

Comment: Calling that function once when the class object is made is still the cheapest option.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, if you actually end up calling all of the expensive methods (and whatever they are returning is actually available at definition time). If you have many expensive methods, it is probably better to only execute those you actually need.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Also, that option is now available as an answer, [by Laxmi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49255464/4042267), which I upvoted.